# How to change Button Border CornerRadius?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I just don't understand why my code doesn't work. And I just want to change only one Button's border, I have seen someone using `TargetType="{x:Type Button}"`,It doesn't meet my demand! And the answer in [Set CornerRadius on button template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681022/set-cornerradius-on-button-template) explains how to change the CornerRadius, I know how to change the CornerRadius, but I really don't know why my Code doesn't work for only one button.

```
<Button Content="OK" BorderThickness="1">
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set CornerRadius on button template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681022/set-cornerradius-on-button-template)

Comment: I see many typing mistakes in your code. Is that the reason? I corrected all of them and code is working fine at my end.

Comment: Your current code will work only if `Border` is present in `Button.Content`, and not in its `Template`.

Comment: @NareshRavlani sorry about my typing mistakes. The corrected code is working fine, but the CornerRadius of my Button isn't changed

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I somewhat knows how to fix it...

Comment: @Grey: Then some other code is causing that issue as provided code is working fine for different corner radius at my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are a novice, i suggest you detach the Button in Blend to learn how to change the border

Comment: Thx for your answer