# One Side rounded corner buttons in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rounded-corners

In the Project, there are two adjacent buttons.
The style should make the outer side of the two buttons in rounded corner buttons in WPF. Here is the button image how they should look

[image]

The below solution XAML style code makes both sides rounded. But I need the outer side rounded only.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6746271/4002198

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681022/set-cornerradius-on-button-template

Comment: Tweak CornerRadius to get the desired effect. eg. CornerRadius ="8,0,0,8"

Comment: Nice! Happy to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Yves. I am positing the full syle code so that someone can use it for the same purpose.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCornerRightSelected" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="grid">
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="0,10,10,0" 
                     BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" 
                                                    ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#0073CF"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#0073CF"/>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      TextElement.FontWeight="Bold">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>

                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" 
                                            CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#40b5f2" Offset="0.3"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#40b5f2" Offset="0.3"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" 
                       Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="grid" Value="0.25"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```