# Can't pass CornerRadius through TemplateBinding/TemplatedParent

Tags: wpf

I have a style for `Button`s and now I want to apply it to `RadioButton`s, except that where a normal `Button` has a `CornerRadius` that is a single number (each corner is the same) I want to render the `RadioButton`s with different corner radii, like this:

[image]

I use a custom `ControlTemplate` for `Button` as well as a style:

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}" x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
            CornerRadius="22.5"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
        <TextBlock FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30 0"
                    Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}" x:Key="MainButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource IntBlue2}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource IntBlue2}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="132"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#66CDFF"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And I have a style for `RadioButton` that uses the `Button` template

```xml
<Style TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundPureWhite}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledGrey}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Everything above works, until I want the custom `CornerRadius` for each `RadioButton`.

I've tried `CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"` inside the `Border` in the `ControlTemplate`, and `<Setter Property="Border.CornerRadius" Value="22.5"/>` inside the `MainButton` style, but it doesn't work (it doesn't apply the radius).

Binding `CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"` to the border in the template doesn't even compile, and setting `CornerRadius` on a `Button` or `RadioButton`, through the control tag or through a setter in the style, also doesn't compile.

How do I use one template, but different `CornerRadius` in each style or instance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set CornerRadius on button template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681022/set-cornerradius-on-button-template)

Answer (score 1):

A `ButtonBase` has no `CornerRadius` property that you can bind to but you could use the `Tag` property:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}" x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
            CornerRadius="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
            ...

<Style TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="22.5" />
    ...
</Style>

<RadioButton ... Tag="0" />
```

Comment: @JonathanTuzman: Does this answer your question or what's left to it?