# Why is my WPF style for CornerRadius not being applied in Windows 7?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-7, windows-10, wpf-style

I created a simple WPF App while [answering an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58450755/4516834), my solution works on my Windows 10 machine, but when I run the app on my Windows 7 laptop the style isn't being applied. I believe this is something to do with Window's style setting over riding my style, how can I force it to use mine instead?

I'm running the same .exe on both machines.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CircleButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="1000"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource CircleButton}"/>
    <Button Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource CircleButton}"/>
    <Button Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource CircleButton}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Windows 10 running .NET 4.8 (App targeting 4.6.2)
[image: Screenshot of three circles produced by the example code in Windows 10 running .NET 4.8 (App targeting 4.6.2)]
Windows 7 running .NET 4.7.2 (App targeting 4.6.2)
[image: Screenshot of three circles produced by the example code in Windows 7 running .NET 4.7.2 (App targeting 4.6.2)]

Comment: Have you tried with the same .NET versions? Also, does this `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" x:Key="CircleButton">` can help for solving issue?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I managed to find a Windows 10 machine with 4.7.2 on it and it applies the style correctly, so confident its not a .NET issue, but a Windows issue. I tried adding the BasedOn bit without any luck as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default style on Windows 7 defined in `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll` uses a `ButtonChrome` element instead of a `Border` element, which is why adding your implicit `Border` style has no effect.

If you want to apply the Windows 10 style on Windows 7, you could copy the entire `ControlTemplate` that is defined in `PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll` on Windows 8 and later and set the `Template` property in your `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="CircleButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="1000"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

You can extract the default template by right-clicking on a `Button` element in design mode in Visual Studio on Windows 10 and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy.